# How to create button for each scene (Level) at run-time. Unity3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I was looking all over the web on How to create a button for each scene(level) at runtime dynamically but couldn't find. I found that you can reference unity scene file in inspector by using a public variable of type Object, and also SceneAsset but that seems to work only in the editor and when the game is built for Android it doesn't work. I don't want to create each button and then pass sceneName parameter for each scene manually.

Comment: Do you plan on having different scenes at runtime then you do when you build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really broad ...

To get the scenes into a list in the Inspector I used this:

```
public class ScenePathManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Serializable]
    public class SceneElement
    {
        string Path;
        string Name;
    }

    public List<SceneElement> Scenes = new List<SceneElement>();

    // Loading scenes by path is more secure
    // since two scenes might have the same name
    // but the path is always unique
    public void LoadScene(string path)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            Debug.LogError("Given path is null or empty!", this);
            return;
        }

        if(!Scenes.Any(s=>string.Equals(s.Path, path)))
        {
            Debug.LogError("Given path " + path + " is invalid!", this);
            return;
        }

        // Load the Scene here e.g. using
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(path);
    }
}
```

the editor script (this has to be placed in a folder called `Editor`)

```
using UnityEditor

[CustomEditor(typeof(ScenePathManager))]
private partial class ScenePathManagerEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _scenes;

    private ReorderableList _sceneList;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _scenes = serializedObject.FindProperty("Scenes");

        _sceneList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, _scenes)
        {
            displayAdd = true,
            displayRemove = true,
            draggable = true,
            drawHeaderCallback = rect => EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, "Scenes"),
            drawElementCallback = (rect, index, selected, highlighted) =>
            {
                var element = _scenes.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);
                var path = element.FindPropertyRelative("Path");
                var name = element.FindPropertyRelative("Name");

                // get the SceneAsset that belongs to the current path
                var scene = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<SceneAsset>(path.stringValue);

                // draw an object field in the editor
                scene = (SceneAsset)EditorGUI.ObjectField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width * 0.5f, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), scene, typeof(SceneAsset), false);

                // write back the path of the SceneAsset
                path.stringValue = AssetDatabase.GetAssetOrScenePath(scene);
                name.stringValue = scene.name;
            },
            elementHeight = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 1.2f
        };
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawScriptField();

        serializedObject.Update();

        // Disable editing of the list on runtime
        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
        _sceneList.DoLayoutList();
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    // Draws the usual Script field in the Inspector
    private void DrawScriptField()
    {
        // Disable editing
        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
        EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Script", MonoScript.FromMonoBehaviour((ScenePathManager)target), typeof(ScenePathManager), false);
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
    }
}
```

Now you **can** simply reference Scene assets and get the according ScenePaths and Names.

---

Now to the buttons. Simpliest way is having one button prefab and instantiate and configure the buttons on runtime like e.g.

```
public class ButtonSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    // somehow get this reference e.g. via drag and drop in the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private ScenePathManager _scenePathManager;

    // reference your prefab here
    [SerializeField] private Button _buttonPrefab;

    public void SpawnButtons()
    {
        foreach(var scene in _scenePathManager.Scenes)
        {
            // ofcourse you will want to spawn this maybe as
            // child of another object or position them etc
            var button = Instantiate(_buttonPrefab);

            // However you want to get the text. You could also give each button
            // special MonoBehaviour class and reference all components you need
            var buttonText = button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>(true);

            buttonText.text = scene.Name;

            button.onClick.AddListener(() =>
            {
                _scenePathManager.LoadScene(scene.Path);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

You even could automatically add all scenes that are referenced to the build settings (I used this only for additive scene loading but it's only an idea ;) )

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    public void AddListsToBuildSettings()
    {
        var editorBuildSettingsScenes = new List<EditorBuildSettingsScene>
        {
            // Pre-add the current Scene
            new EditorBuildSettingsScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().path, true)
        };

        // Add all scenes in ScenePaths to the EditorBuildSettings
        foreach (var scene in ScenePaths)
        {
            // ignore unsaved scenes
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(scene?.Path)) continue;

            // skip if scene already in buildSettings
            if (editorBuildSettingsScenes.Any(s => string.Equals(s.path, scene))) continue;

            editorBuildSettingsScenes.Add(new EditorBuildSettingsScene(scene.Path, true));
        }

        // Set the Build Settings window Scene list
        EditorBuildSettings.scenes = editorBuildSettingsScenes.ToArray();
    }
#endif
```

Comment: I dont understand ScenePaths class. It seems it does not exist.  ScenePaths.Contains(path)

Comment: sorry fixed it ... I changed the structure a bit and forgot that part ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a prefab of the button? You could also create a script that gets the scene name from `SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name` and then attach that script to your prefab. You could then initialize an object of that prefab on runtime with:

```
(GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("MyPrefab"))
```

Finally, you would have to reference your canvas in that script, so that you can set it as it's child.

Answer (score 0):

The `SceneAsset` only works in the editor (that's why it's in the `UnityEditor` namespace.) The runtime representation of a scene is the `Scenemangement.Scene` class, but, unfortunately, it can't be easily set in the inspector.

You can work around that limitation in a number of ways:

1. If you don't use asset bundles, you could make use of `SceneManager.GetSceneAt` to get each scene by index. Combined with `SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings`, it's probably the simplest way to make sure you include every scene in the build.
2. If your scene names stay consistent, you could simply use an array of strings that you set in the inspector.
3. If your scene names follow a pattern, you could write your code assuming that pattern (for example: if scenes are named "Level_1", "Level_2", etc, then you'd know that `"Level_"+n` is a valid scene, if n is between 1 and the total number of levels). This is a bit more brittle than hardcoding the full names (if a scene is ever added that doesn't follow the convention, it won't work) but has less maintainence overhead when new scenes are added.
4. If you need a system that is future-proof and mistake-resistant, then you could create a custom inspector. This can be as simple or as feature-rich as you want, but any custom inspector implementation would need to convert the choice in the inspector into the scene name and/or path so that it can be used in the runtime. (The [answer provided by @derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55523389/11156116) uses this approach, as do some of the answers on a [similar Unity Answers topic](https://answers.unity.com/questions/242794/inspector-field-for-scene-asset.html).)

Personally, I have used naming convention (#3 above), when I needed to do this in the past, but that was a single-person project, so the training cost of using a naming convention was effectively zero.